# Hive output created one huge part file and many small part files

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm currently facing a problem using joins in HIVE. Joining two large tables results in one big file and many small files in the output. Following is my scenario in detail

- Table A has columns x_address, y_address, z_address in addition to other columns which are of type string.
- Columns x_address, y_address, z_address carry a hashkey for a address
  column in Table A.
- Table A has approximately 110 million records
- Table B is a lookup table which provides the latitude and longitude
  for a specific Address.
- The key (address_key) in table B is the hashkey of an address

My HQL is

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE FINAL_TABLE    
SELECT 
    a.x_address_full, 
    b1.lat,
    b1.long,
    a.y_address_full, 
    b2.lat,
    b2.long,
    a.z_address_full, 
    b3.lat,
    b3.long,
    FROM 
    TABLE_A a 
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b1 ON a.x_address = b1.address_key
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b2 ON a.x_address = b2.address_key
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b3 ON a.x_address = b3.address_key
```

In the Filebrowser (Hue) I see there are approx 50 part files created.

```
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user 103488475533 2015-09-08 20:18 FINAL_TABLE/000000_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18887004 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000001_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     16806648 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000002_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     17759878 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000003_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     19229971 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000004_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     17361505 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000005_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     20935119 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000006_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18525756 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000007_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18155867 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000008_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18388192 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000009_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     17352032 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000010_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     20586196 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000011_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     19026628 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000012_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18492712 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000013_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     20525139 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000014_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18767626 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000015_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18759833 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000016_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     17625431 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000017_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     17589284 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000018_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     19635568 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000019_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18782632 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000020_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     18468366 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000021_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     19348518 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000022_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     19132130 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000023_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 user user     19661123 2015-09-08 16:43 FINAL_TABLE/000024_0
```

Note: All the tables are AvroSerDe based.

Based on my analysis so far, this probably seems to be due to a who load of Skewness in the x_address or y_address or z_address fields which have mostly one value.

Any thoughts?.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: yes. How could I avoid data skewness?